# Skipping top level of JSON data and retrieving data below it via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, javascript-objects

Via a microservice, I retrieve several packages of JSON data and spit them out onto a Vue.js-driven page.   The data looks something like this:

```
{"data":{"getcompanies":
  [
   {"id":6,"name":"Arena","address":"12 Baker Street","zip":"15090"}, 
   {"id":7,"name":"McMillan","address":null,"zip":"15090"},
   {"id":8,"name":"Ball","address":"342 Farm Road","zip":"15090"}
  ]
 }}

{"data":{"getusers":
  [{"id":22,"name":"Fred","address":"Parmesean Street","zip":"15090"}, 
   {"id":24,"name":"George","address":"Loopy Lane","zip":"15090"},
   {"id":25,"name":"Lucy","address":"Farm Road","zip":"15090"}]}}

{"data":{"getdevices":
  [{"id":2,"name":"device type 1"}, 
   {"id":4,"name":"device type 2"},
   {"id":5,"name":"device type 3"}]}}
```

...and I successfully grab them individually via code like this:

```
getCompanies() {
  this.sendMicroServiceRequest({
    method: 'GET',
    url: `api/authenticated/function/getcompanies`
  })
  .then((response) => {
    if(response.data) {
      this.dataCompanies = response.data.getcompanies    
    } else {
      console.error(response)
    }
  }).catch(console.error)
}
```

...with `getUsers()` and `getDevices()` looking respectively the same.  getCompanies() returns:

```
[{"id":6,"name":"Arena","address":"12 Baker Street","zip":"15090"}, 
 {"id":7,"name":"McMillan","address":null,"zip":"15090"},
 {"id":8,"name":"Ball","address":"342 Farm Road","zip":"15090"}]
```

...which I relay to the Vue template in a table, and this works just fine and dandy.

But this is obviously going to get unwieldy if I need to add more microservice calls down the road.

What I'm looking for is an elegant way to jump past the `response.data.*whatever*` and get to those id-records with a re-useable call, but I'm having trouble getting there.   `response.data[0]` doesn't work, and mapping down to the stuff I need either comes back undefined, or in bits of array.  And filtering for `response.data[0].id` to return just the rows with ids keeps coming back undefined.

My last attempt (see below) to access the data does work, but looks like it comes back as individual array elements.  I'd rather not - if possible - rebuild an array into a JSON structure.  I keep thinking I *should* be able to just step past the next level regardless of what it's called, and grab whatever is there in one chunk, as if I read `response.data.getcompanies` directly, but not caring what '`getcompanies`' is, or needing to reference it by name:

```
// the call
this.dataCompanies = this.getFullData('companies')

getFullData(who) {
  this.sendMicroServiceRequest({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'api/authenticated/function/get' + who,
  })
  .then((response) => {
    if(response) {
      // attempt 1 to get chunk below 'getcompanies'
      Object.keys(response.data).forEach(function(prop) {
        console.log(response.data[prop])
      })
      
      // attempt 2
      // for (const prop in response.data) {
      //  console.log(response.data[prop])
      // }

     let output = response.data[prop]  // erroneously thinking this is in one object
     return output

    } else {
      console.error(response)
    }
  }).catch(console.error)
}
```

...outputs:

```
(63) [{…}, {…}, {…}]  <-- *there are 63 of these records, I'm just showing the first few...*
0: {"id":6,"name":"Arena","address":"12 Baker Street","zip":"15090"}
1: {"id":7,"name":"McMillan","address":null,"zip":"15090"},     
2: {"id":8,"name":"Ball","address":"342 Farm Road","zip":"15090"}...
```

Oh, and the `return` above comes back 'undefined' for some reason that eludes me at 3AM.  >.<

It's one of those things where I *think* I am close, but not quite.   Any tips, hints, or pokes in the right direction are greatly appreciated.

Comment: `prop` only exists in the function that defines it; that is, inside the `forEach`. You could just use `response.data[Object.keys(response.data)[0]]`...

Comment: that returns a list of individual arrays - which I did not need.  I was already getting the returned data in that format in my example code at the end of the post.  but thanks for the shortcut!

Comment: Where in your question do you mention how you want the data to appear at the end?

Comment: the part where I said '... I'd rather not - if possible - rebuild an array into a JSON structure.   I keep thinking I should be able to just step past the next level regardless of what it's called, and grab whatever is there in one chunk, as if I read response.data.getcompanies directly, but not caring what 'getcompanies' is, or needing to reference it by name:..'   :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel it's better to be explicit about accessing the object. Seems like the object key is consistent with the name of the microservice function? If so:

```
getData(functionName) {
    return this.sendMicroServiceRequest({
        method: 'GET',
        url: "api/authenticated/function/" + functionName
    })
    .then( response => response.data[functionName] )
}
getCompanies(){
    this.getData("getcompanies").then(companies => {
        this.dataCompanies = companies
    })
}
```

Comment: I thought of that too, but was looking to skip the extra intermediate getCompanies() function and just get the data saved directly into the object that Vue uses to display the table, ie:   this.dataCompanies = getData('companies')

Comment: I ended up using your solution and coupled it with @thank-you 's async suggestions.  Great stuff! Thanks to everyone for your time.

Answer (score 1):

```js
let arrResponse = {data: ['x']};
let objResponse = {data: {getcompanies: 'x'}};

console.log(arrResponse.data[0]);
console.log(Object.values(objResponse.data)[0]);
```

`response.data[0]` would work if `data` was an array. To get the first-and-only element of an object, use `Object.values(response.data)[0]` instead. `Object.values` converts an object to an array of its values.

Its counterparts `Object.keys` and `Object.entries` likewise return arrays of keys and key-value tuples respectively.

Note, order isn't guaranteed in objects, so this is only predictable in your situation because `data` has exactly a single key & value. Otherwise, you'd have to iterate the entry tuples and search for the desired entry.

Comment: I understood all that, but starting at [0] starts..well..at the top..or rather at the first level. and as you pointed out, the value(s) are returned as arrays - which was what i was trying to avoid - rebuilding an object from a list of arrays, instead of just accessing the value as an object itself.

Answer (score 1):

**firstValue**

Let's begin with a generic function, `firstValue`. It will get the first *value* of an object, if present, otherwise it will throw an error -

```js
const x = { something: "foo" }
const y = {}

const firstValue = t =>
{ const v = Object.values(t)
  if (v.length)
    return v[0]
  else
    throw Error("empty data")
}

console.log(firstValue(x)) // "foo"
console.log(firstValue(y)) // Error: empty data
```

**getData**

Now write a generic `getData`. We chain our `firstValue` function on the end, and be careful not to add a `console.log` or `.catch` here; that is a choice for the caller to decide -

```js
getData(url) {
  return this
    .sendMicroServiceRequest({ method: "GET", url })
    .then(response => {
      if (response.data)
        return response.data
      else
        return Promise.reject(response)
    })
    .then(firstValue)
}
```

Now we write `getCompanies`, `getUsers`, etc -

```js
getCompanies() {
  return getData("api/authenticated/function/getcompanies")
}

getUsers() {
  return getData("api/authenticated/function/getusers")
}

//...
```

**async and await**

Maybe you could spruce up `getData` with `async` and `await` -

```js
async getData(url) {
  const response =
    await this.sendMicroServiceRequest({ method: "GET", url })
  return response.data
    ? firstValue(response.data)
    : Promise.reject(response)
}
```

**power of generics demonstrated**

We might even suggest that these `get*` functions are no longer needed -

```js
async getAll() {
  return {
    companies:
      await getData("api/authenticated/function/getcompanies"),
    users:
      await getData("api/authenticated/function/getusers"),
    devices:
      await getData("api/authenticated/function/getdevices"),
    // ...
  }
}
```

Above we used three `await getData(...)` requests which happen in serial order. Perhaps you want all of these requests to run in parallel. Below we will show how to do that -

```js
async getAll() {
  const requests = [
    getData("api/authenticated/function/getcompanies"),
    getData("api/authenticated/function/getusers"),
    getData("api/authenticated/function/getdevices")
  ]
  const [companies, users, devices] = Promise.all(requests)
  return { companies, users, devices }
}
```

**error handling**

Finally, error handling is reserved for the caller and should not be attempted within our generic functions -

```js
this.getAll()
  .then(data => this.render(data)) // some Vue template
  .catch(console.error)
```

Comment: Loved the explanations - it definitely filled in some gaps I had.   I ended up using @ben-west 's solution and coupled it with your async suggestions.  Great stuff! Thanks for your time.

Comment: I'm happy to help. Cheers